# how to fetch object in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

```
        $sql = "select userId,UserName from User_Master(nolock) where UserName = '$username'"; //Need to change query for location. 
        $results = DB::select($sql);    
        $userId = $results[0]['userId'];
```

Im unable to print $userId in this way. What is the correct syntax in laravel

Comment: what do you mean by you are unable to print $userId?

Comment: actually this function used in an API so i m unable to find the error.. but im damn sour there is an error in line $userId = $results[0]['userId']; according to laravel syntex

Comment: Have you tried `$results[0]->userId`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get userId using:

```
$userId = $results[0]->userId;
```

However there are some problems with your code. First you should make sure you have such record so it should be rather something like this:

```
$userId = $results ? $results[0]->userId : null;
```

In addition you should consider SQL injection, so the safer would be using:

```
$sql = "select userId,UserName from User_Master(nolock) where UserName = ?"; //Need to change query for location. 
$results = DB::select($sql, [$username]);    
$userId = $results ? $results[0]->userId : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not much familiar with `laravel` but you must have to follow standard structure to write query in `laravel`. As per laravel documentation you need to change your query like following:

```
$results = DB::table('User_Master(nolock)')
                     ->select(DB::raw('userId , UserName'))
                     ->where('UserName', '=', $username)
                     ->get();
print_r($results); // You can see your query result here
```

For more information check [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects).

**Edit**

As per @Ethan22 suggestion and laravel Documentation:

The `select` method will always return an `array` of results. Each result within the array will be a `PHP StdClass object`.

So you need to try with `$results[0]->userId`

Comment: Not quite, you can put a straight string into that function like he's doing. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries

Comment: @Ethan22 thanks buddy for your suggestion. I am not much familiar with `laravel`... :)